# How do use WCF to communicate between an Application and a Windows Service?

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I've gone through some tutorials on creating a WCF service.  I'm using Visual Studio 2012.  I got a very simple WCF Service Library (vb.net) and Windows Application (vb.net) communicating via WCF.  That's a start.

However, my project requires I do the following:

- My Windows Service - This is already an application that has it's tasks.
- My Application - This is an application that is already developed as well.

I need the service to talk to the application.  The service will need to send the following information to the windows application:

- Status Updates
- Metric Information (mostly integers for counts)

I need the application to send information to the service.  It would need to send:

- Reload Configuration command

Should be relatively simple, but I've never worked with WCF until today.  So I have some questions...

1. Do I need to re-work my current windows service into a WCF Service?
2. Since it won't be in IIS, do I also create a WCF Service Library or do I roll this into the windows service somehow?
3. What is the best way to set up the different types of communication? (i.e., sending over specific metrics and reload commands)

Probably the main question is what components, in addition to my current windows service and application, will I need to make this work?

I hope that was clear :(  I think I'm confusing it all... but I hope not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Windows service can host the WCF service. Similarly, if you want, your application can host a WCF service. The application could talk to the WCF service in the Windows Service, and the Windows Service's WCF could talk to the one in the application. Depending on the nature of the communication, you could also just use a callback channel to permit the Windows Service's WCF to call back to the application.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should configure your [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) windows service to use [named pipes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5830/Using-MSMQ-from-C). If your windows service is already built then the easiest way to do it would be to build another one as a WCF windows service and wrap the already existing functionality.

Hope I helped!